# WPF & MEF UserControl part of a larger view (In design mode)

Tags: wpf, mef

I want this usercontrol to be Created via MEF but also to have the usercontrol positioned and properties set on it in Blend...  How can I force the composition of the imports that the usercontrol requires when I have a 'Concrete' reference to the usercontrol ?

What happended to PartsInitializer.Satisfy ?

Export for the UserControl

```
    [Export(typeof(IWOFlyOutFilterMenuView))]
public partial class FlyoutTab_WOsViewFilter : UserControl,IWOFlyOutFilterMenuView,IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
```

No Imports in the Containing view as it is a concrete instance.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: `PartInitializer` only exists in Silverlight, not in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the composition when you have an instance like this:

1. Import the namespace System.ComponentModel.Composition (to include the extension method SatisfyImportsOnce
2. Create a CompositionContainer
3. Call SatisfyImportsOnce on the composition Container and supply it the instance of the usercontrol.

Take care,
Martin